# В чем отличия указателя self от this?

Tags: php

Что-то не совсем ясно.

Comment: Удалите лишние метки. В php вопрос имеет смысл, в java не знаю, в javascript нет self.

Comment: В php self:: для констант и статичных методов. Видимо метка "java" лишняя.

Comment: В Java self нет (по крайней мере среди ключевых слов, по аналогии с this и super).

Comment: self относится ко всему классу, а $this только к объекту (методу)
Мог бы не полениться поискать в гугле. )

Answer (score 1):

В php **self** - указать на класс, например, если существует класс AAA и у него есть статический метод func, то вызвать из любого места можно через AAA::func() (если он public разумеется).

Однако если вы хотите вызвать статический метод из экземпляра текущего класса или другого статического метода текущего класса, то php предоставляет краткий псевдоним в виде self::func(), что эквивалентно AAA::func() в рамках текущего класса. Выгода self очевидно, если имя текущего класса больще 4 символов :) и к тому же так легче в последствии будет переименовать класс - не придется везде по коду этого класса переправлять его имя.

**this** - указатель на экземпляр класса, внутри исполняемого метода этого экземпляра (объекта).